# Node.js stops when terminal is closed

Tags: node.js, linode

I am using a Fedro server for deploying node.js code.
I have kept my code inside /var/www/example.com/   
Whenever the terminal is open I can access the API as soon as I close the terminal I am not able to access it.  
Also I had tried using nohup command for executing the process in background.But what I had read is whenever we reboot the system it will no longer be running in background.  

How to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: run it inside screen? why reboot the system?

Comment: Try to use forever.js

Comment: I tried using the  forever start path to my node.js file. But the same thing is happening.

Answer (score 4):

You can run the program inside a screen. Whenever you close the screen your program will keep running.

**Create a screen**

```
screen -S <screen_name>
```

Now you will be switched to screen and run the node server in this screen.

Use ctrl + C to close the server.

Closing screen by 'x' icon won't close the program running inside screen.

**Listing out screen**

```
screen -list
```

Your created screen will be displayed in the list. You will be able to identify it by screen name. Also, id will be shown against the name

**Go back to screen**

```
screen -dr <id>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi check kindly check PM2 for node.
https://github.com/Unitech/pm2

PM2 is a production process manager for Node.js applications with a built-in load balancer. It allows you to keep applications alive forever, to reload them without downtime and to facilitate common system admin tasks.

We are using PM2 on our project and your problem regarding the application will stop when you do a server restart try checking init.d

Answer (score 0):

To end the program, you should be using Ctrl + C. If you do that, it sends SIGINT, which allows the program to end gracefully, unbinding from any ports it is listening on.

See also: https://superuser.com/a/262948/48624

Comment: But it kill the process and the API is not accessible for me. I want process should be running even when I do Ctrl + C or Terminal is closed.

Comment: I am using fedro os on linode server